# Sequence of random variables and convergence in probability.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $\Omega:=[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure.Let's define a sequence $X_n= \frac{\omega}{n}$.
Check:

**a)** Convergence in distribution

**b)** Convergence in probability

My solution:
**b)**
$P(|X_n-X| \ge \epsilon)=P(|X_n| \ge \epsilon)=P(\frac{\omega}{n} \ge \epsilon)=P(\omega \ge \epsilon n )$
And this is equal 0 for each $\epsilon >0$ and $ n \to \infty$.

**a)**
$X \equiv 0$

We have $F_X(t)= \begin{cases} 0 &\text{for } t < 0\\1 &\text{for } t \ge  0\end{cases}$

Now we have to calculate $F_{X_n}$ and here I have problem.

Answer (score 0):

Convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution, so having done b) you do not need to do a).

Comment: Ok, but I have problem with a.

Comment: You shouldn't have, as you did b) and b) => a). But ok, if you want to do it without using b), then you can see that F_X_n(t) =  0 for t<0, 1 for t>1/n,  and it is linear on [0,1/n], so nt for t \in [0,1/n].